# Sass target parent element from child

Tags: css, sass

I'm currently learning [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/), so if this seems obvious, don't laugh! 
I have a unordered list, which on li > a hover the ul background changes.
Changing the a link background is simple enough, but how do I target the ul element? I've tried using &, ~ and < which has been advised on several online tutorials, but I've had no luck. Any and all help would be appreciated, Thank you.

```
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;

  li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;

    a {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      display: block;
      font-size: 60px;
      font-size: 3.75rem;
      color: rgb(255,255,255);
      font-family: 'Cera PRO Medium';
      text-decoration: none;

      &:hover & li & ul {
        background-color: red;
      }

    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, just add hover property to `ul` element:

```
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;

  &:hover {
    background-color: red;
  }
  ...
```

https://fiddle.jshell.net/fo214wkd/

Comment: I needed the parent ul background-colour to change when hovering either the child li or child li > a not when hovering the parent ul.

Answer (score 0):

This can't be achieved with normal CSS, even with SASS. You'll need to use a jQuery or other JavaScript alternative to achieve this.

In the [CSS Level 4 draft](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#relational) there is a `:has` pseudo selector which could achieve this, however that's only a dream at the moment.

I know this isn't a jQuery question, however a very basic jQuery example would be:

```
$j("a").on("mouseover", function() {

    $j(this).parent("ul").addClass("hovering");

}), (function() {

    $j(this).parent("ul").removeClass("hovering");

});
```